# Splashscreen is only showed sometimes

Tags: java, android

I defined a splashscreen the following way:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ExceptionHandler.register(this);
        setFullscreen();
        splashScreen();
    }

private void splashScreen() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
                splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreenLayer);
                startSplashTime = new Date();
            }
        });

        new LoadingThread().start(); 
    }

private class LoadingThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            checkNetwork();
        }

    }
```

Somewhere at specific conditions in the checkNetwork() method, the stopSplash method is called:

```
public void stopSplash() {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = STOPSPLASH;

        Date endSplashTime = new Date();
        long time = endSplashTime.getTime() - startSplashTime.getTime();
        System.out.println("Time Splashscreen was displayed: " + time);
        if (time < SPLASH_MIN_TIME) {
            long delay = SPLASH_MIN_TIME - time;
            System.out.println("Delay Splashscreen for: " + delay);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            splashHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Show Splashscreen now");
            splashHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case STOPSPLASH:
                    splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }

    };
```

The problem is, sometimes (maybe 1 of 10) if I started the app directly from Eclipse, the Splashscreen isn't showed, but instead just a black screen.

Other problem: if i restart the app, e.g. after onDestroy() was called after clicking the back button on the device, the Splashscreen is almost never shown.

Any hints why?

My assumption: could it be, that the LoadingThread starts "faster" than the Runnable, and so the network staff is done before the Splashscreen is set?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a CountdownTimer in your implementation.  On your first activity, start a CountdownTimer that checks in onTick() every so often for a synchronized boolean finishedLoading with some kind of timeout in onFinish() (15 seconds or something), while your loading is done in another thread that sets finishedLoading to true when it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the splash screen isnt being terminated before the v=next activity starts.. just a thought..